# Documentation for Rails .where function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where can I find documentation for the `where()` method?

I came across code like this:

```
  def train(min_feature_freq = 3,test_split = 0.2,verbose=false)

    liked = Story.where(:like => true)
    disliked = Story.where(:like => false)
```

https://github.com/joelgrus/hackernews/blob/master/model.rb

It has "`Story.where"`. I searched google, did not find document for this `where`() method.
The `Story` class does not define it either. https://github.com/joelgrus/hackernews/blob/master/story.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://github.com/joelgrus/hackernews/blob/master/story.rb

... you see:

```
class Story
  include MongoMapper::Document
```

So you'd either look here:

https://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper

Or there:

http://mongomapper.com/documentation/

For documentation. For the documentation of `.where` you'd look here, specifically:

http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/querying.html#where

Answer (score 2):

The two answers provide the solution for this particular case, but in general, when you want to know what class the method is defined in, do as:

```
 p Story.method(:where).owner
```

and to find out where it is defined, do as:

```
 p Story.method(:where).source_location
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Rails Guide on querying. It will tell you about the where function and more!

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions

Also, check here for more documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where

Comment: I don't think they are using ActiveRecord there.